# VBA- increase the selected formula by one row

Tags: vba, excel

Cell `O21` has the formula `=AVERAGE(F67:F88)` in it.

I want to use VBA code to automate this to update each week to include the next row of data below, so next week it would be `=AVERAGE(F67:F89)` week after `=AVERAGE(F67:F90)`.

I don't have a last row as  the data sheet is pretty big - can I do this?

Comment: You most certainly can do that! It's unlikely that anyone will be willing to write it for you though, but if you run into trouble with your code and have a specific issue, you're sure to get help fixing it. You may want to try the Macro Recorder if you're not sure where to start. It writes functional, but horrible code, but it will give you a good kick-off point. In the meantime, take the [tour] and read the [help] to find out what makes for a good question.

Comment: Split that second number from the formula, increment it by one, re-write the formula to the cell.

Comment: Also, search here for how to find the last used row, and use that technique to completely rewrite the formula. Either would work.

Comment: Create a dynamic named range and refer to that in your vba

Comment: Select any cell in your range, click "Format as table" from the "Home" Ribbon; pick any style (doesn't matter which) - and now you have an actual *table* presumably named `Table1`. Change your formula to `=AVERAGE(Table1[NameOfThe6thColumn])` and you never need to update it ever again, manually or through VBA.

Comment: Look at using `dynamic named ranges`  will sort itself out

Comment: did think of that but i'm using previous years data also that is already available, that's why i wanted to be able to just drop down a row each time a new week is added from the current year and the previous year so i am comparing like for like etc

Answer (score 1):

You don't need VBA code to automate this. Excel handles it "natively". Have column headings in the first row of your "table":

[image: columns A-C contain data in rows 2-4; headings in row 1]

Now select "Format as Table" from the "Home" tab of the Ribbon. Excel selects the whole area and infers that there are column headers:

[image: "where is the data for your table?" dialog]

Now you're looking at an actual *table* that Excel understands as such. And you can name it whatever you want:

[image: Table Name is in the "Table Tools" Ribbon tab]

Use *table references* instead of plain range addresses:

[image: =AVERAGE(TableName[ColumnName])]

And now when you add a new table row, the formula doesn't need to be adjusted in any way:

[image: average recalculates automatically after adding a new value]

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use:

```
=AVERAGE(F67:F9999)
```

and insure that the values in F88 through F9999 are all **blank** until they are assigned new values.

This is because `AVERAGE()` will ignore all the blanks in its range.

This way you can add data on a weekly basis and not have to update the formula each week.

Comment: did think of that but i'm using previous years data also that is already available, that's why i wanted to be able to just drop down a row each time a new week is added from the current year and the previous year so i am comparing like for like etc.